# Right sidebar overlapping page border

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I have following right sidebar which overlapping page border when browse resize,
I need position to be fixed so stays fixed when scrolling page, I searched stack for hours, tried different options but no success, not sure maybe media query can help here:

```
<div class="block-cat" style="background: #f3f3f3; padding: 20px; position: fixed; width:20%">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `position:absolute` on behalf of `position:fixed` and set your width

Comment: like this <div class="block-cat" style="background: #f3f3f3; padding: 20px; position: absolute; width:20%">  Not sure about width, it already set?

Comment: it doesn't help